# Ubuntu 18.4 not showing full amount of RAM

Tags: ubuntu

I have an threadripper system with 16gb of RAM installed. BIOS shows both 8gb sticks of RAM.

dmidecode shows both sticks but free -m and top are only showing 7899mb of available memory.

```
root@threadripper-1:~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7899         501        7112           1         285        7142
Swap:             0           0           0
```

```
root@threadripper-1:~# dmidecode -t memory
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 512 GB
        Error Information Handle: 0x000D
        Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000E
        Error Information Handle: 0x0014
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: Unknown
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: Unknown
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: Unknown
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Unknown
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000E
        Error Information Handle: 0x0016
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: Unknown
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: Unknown
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: Unknown
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Unknown
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000E
        Error Information Handle: 0x0018
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL C
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: F4-3200C16-8GTZR
        Rank: 1
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000E
        Error Information Handle: 0x001A
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL D
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: F4-3200C16-8GTZR
        Rank: 1
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
```

any ideas / suggetsions on how to get the full 16gb available?

Adding cat /proc/meminfo as requested

```
ukcsgo@threadripper-1:~$ cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        8089456 kB
MemFree:         7275396 kB
MemAvailable:    7307992 kB
Buffers:           30220 kB
Cached:           192672 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           144488 kB
Inactive:         126140 kB
Active(anon):      49204 kB
Inactive(anon):      156 kB
Active(file):      95284 kB
Inactive(file):   125984 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               276 kB
Writeback:            16 kB
AnonPages:         47784 kB
Mapped:            52872 kB
Shmem:              1628 kB
Slab:             374160 kB
SReclaimable:      73044 kB
SUnreclaim:       301116 kB
KernelStack:        9088 kB
PageTables:         4240 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     4044728 kB
Committed_AS:     768268 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      190504 kB
DirectMap2M:     3883008 kB
DirectMap1G:     4194304 kB
```

Comment: Can you please print out the `cat /proc/meminfo` file? It should be showing the full memory. Otherwise something is dividing? maybe a memory configuration?

Comment: edited original post with output

Comment: please also add output of `numactl -H`.   BTW, what's the brand of motherboard, and the brand of the DIMMS?  And TR4 CPU? have you configured the BIOS to run the machine in NUMA mode? or to use the correct XMP profile for your RAM?   1st gen TR & Ryzen were **very** fussy about the DIMMs being used.  Finally, is there any chance you could either swap the 2x8GB for 4x4GB, or just add another 2x8GB?